# Modifying response content returned from ASP.NET Web API using OData QueryableAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

Here is my issue.  I am using ASP.NET Web API 2.0 and the QueryableAttribute to take advantage of some of the OData filtering functionality.

```
public class VideoController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("activevideos")]
    [Queryable]
    public IEnumerable<Video> GetActiveVideos(ODataQueryOptions<Video> options)
    {
        return new GetvContext().Videos.Where(c => c.IsActive);
    }        
}
```

Now, I have a class that I have been using to modify the response object and contained entities.  This was working fine before I started using the QueryableAttribute.  Before this, I was returning a List from the previous method instead of IEnumerable.

```
public class TestMessageProcessHandler : MessageProcessingHandler
{
    protected override HttpResponseMessage ProcessResponse(
        HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var content = ((ObjectContent)(response.Content)).Value;
        // Do something here with the content.  This used to be a List<Video> 
        // but now the object it is of type: 
        // System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.SelectSome<Content.Api.Video>>
    }
}
```

I need to be able to get the entity from this and I am not sure how to get from type:

`System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.SelectSome<Content.Api.Video>>` to something like `List<Video>` so I can modify the `Video` object.

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with OData, so I could be completely wrong here, but shouldn't that `GetActiveVideos` method return an `IQueryable<Video>` instead an `IEnumerable<Video>`? Although OData might be able to query over it, it will not limit the number of records returned from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[Queryable]` attribute and manage the querying of the data yourself - something like this:

```
public class VideoController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("activevideos")]
    public IList<Video> GetActiveVideos(ODataQueryOptions<Video> options)
    {
        var s = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 1 };
        var result = options.ApplyTo(
            new GetvContext().Videos.Where(c => c.IsActive), s)
            .ToList();

        return result;
    }        
}
```

Comment: One issue is that calling ToList() on the object returned from `options.ApplyTo()` will not compile.  Type arguments cannot be inferred.  

I also cannot do this:

`var result = options.ApplyTo(new GetvContext().Videos.Where(c => c.IsActive), s).AsQueryable().Cast<Video>().ToList();`

because it is unable to cast object of type `'SelectSome'1[Content.Api.Video]' to type 'Content.Api.Video'`

(SelectSome<> is a private class in the OData library)

Comment: The other problem is that I am actually extending QueryableAttribute to get around some other OData idiosyncrasies.  

IF I can get a variation of your method to work and IF there is really no other choice I will use it, but I would really prefer not to have to do this to every single API operation that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do a ToList() - the DbQuery implements IQueryable...

e.g.

```
var content = ((ObjectContent)(response.Content)).Value;
var queryable = content as IQueryable<Video>;
var list = queryable.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting this problem because you specified which fields should be selected by your OData query (for example, `$select=Nr,Date`). If you won't do this, after applying query options OData won't return a `SelectSome` objects, it will return the same objects you are querying, in your case `Video`. So you can easily modify these objects server-side before returning them to client.

And if you need to exclude properties from `Video` object which you don't need, instead of `$select` query option you can use a DTO instead of your `Video` object and include in this DTO only those fields you need.

Yes, this is a workaround, and hopefully there will be better means to do deal with server-side logic in the future versions of this library