# Intercepting and encrypting data in an Odata filter before it is consumed in Asp.net WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

A number of columns in the database are stored in an encrypted format (and we are stuck with this for the foreseeable future)

```
http://localhost/Car?$filter=Name eq 'Ford'
```

I would like to intercept the query and update the filter so that it looks like "Name eq 'ENCRYPTED_TEXT'" so that the query can find the record in the database.

I had a look at queryOptions.Filter and this looks to be the right thing to modify, but I am unsure what is the best way to do this?
Do I just need to de-construct the filter using string manipulation? or is there a better way? 
(I don't want to learn every oddity of odata query string parsing if I can avoid it)

FYI, I need to be able to do this for a couple of columns in every table I expose so a reusable c# solution is required.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the [Queryable] attribute from your specific controller methods and manage the querying of the data yourself. See this post on similar topic...

[Modifying response content returned from ASP.NET Web API using OData QueryableAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569123/modifying-response-content-returned-from-asp-net-web-api-using-odata-queryableat)

Comment: Jason, Thanks for replying. I am aware that I can consume queryOptions directly. The question is regarding what is the best practice for modifying the filter of the queryOptions which your the post you linked to does not cover.

Comment: Unsure if it's best practice but I would probably look into creating a custom action filter attribute which inherits from the QueryableAttribute class specifically for this special handling. Then you could apply this custom attribute to your methods. Here's the MSDN for the attribute...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.queryableattribute%28v=vs.111%29.aspx